# Install OCaml with graphics on mac with homebrew 2.0.0 (-with-x11 no longer possible)

Tags: ocaml, homebrew

Is there an alternative way to install the graphics module for use with ocaml on mac?

Previously, I had used

```
brew install ocaml --with-x11
```

This no longer works, as the package option is no longer supported with brew 2.0.0. Is there another way to get graphics working in ocaml on Mac without this option? I am running Sierra 10.12.6, but am working with a large group running many different mac versions that all need to be able to do this install.

Answer (score 2):

I have had several problems with OCaml and brew. The best option is perhaps to completely remove brew's ocaml, as brew does not support old OS X versions (El Capitan is now unsupported). You can use the OCaml Package Manager [opam](https://opam.ocaml.org) instead.

- To remove OCaml if already installed via brew, type

  ```
  brew remove ocaml
  ```

  then verify that there isn't any `ocaml*` remaining file in `/usr/local/bin`.
- Install opam :

  ```
  sh <(curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ocaml/opam/master/shell/install.sh)`
  ```
- Install OCaml and the Graphics module :

  ```
  opam init --comp=4.07.1
  opam install graphics
  ```
- If not already installed, you may also need to download [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org).

Comment: Thanks! This gets me part of the way there - the graphics module can now be opened from within ocaml. However, it appears that it does not connect with with the x system on Mac, so we cannot open graphics windows, getting the error. `Fatal error: exception Graphics.Graphic_failure("Cannot open display ")`